# discover all hosts in a LAN in VC++

Tags: visual-c++, networking, ping, arp, discovery

just wondering how to discover all hosts (IP, hostname, mac) in my LAN by VC++?

I see someone mention "arp -a", but it seems it doesn't work very well. I also see people mention Ping broadcast address (e.g. 192.168.0.255), but it doesn't work as well.

The only way is to "Ping" or "ARP" the hosts one by one?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not everything will necessarily respond to `PING`. Everything should respond to `ARP`, but polling the network like this is going to be quite slow. The question is: why do you want to do it?

Comment: thanks for the comment. Then the right approach is use multiple threads to do ARP to all hosts one by one?

Comment: as per answering the question "why you want to do it", I am just doing a tool for people to diagnostic network issue (when people complain their ADSL speed is slow, the tool could say: there are a few other PCs in the LAN sharing the bandwdith). :)  But I don't know why you ask this question? will it impact the solution?

Comment: 'Why do it?' I've managed networks as small as 50 and as large as 12,000 users (yes - twelve thousand). I never found a need to sniff out every device on the network. It just doesn't seem very useful, that's all.

Comment: if you don't do sniff every device, they how do you discover all the devices in the network?

Comment: btw, I also see people mention, use UDP broadcast to send request to 137 port (NetBIOS name service), then check which hosts will response.  Then we will know which hosts are in the LAN. Is that a good approach?